# How can I sink a live JSON feed from a RESTful API to BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, polling

I want to persist data from a publicly-accessible API that returns a list of JSON objects, one for each of the past N events, when called. The structure of the JSON objects is simple and consistent. N cannot be specified (to the best of my knowledge), so the API needs to be polled frequently enough that there are no gaps in data. I need to check how frequently that is, but it's definitely more than once a minute.

It doesn't look like BigQuery simply accepts a RESTful API as a streaming data source. The granularity seems to be too fine for Cron, which is usually minutely at best (judging from https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine, it may also exceed quotas). Is there some other option to poll a RESTful API consistently?

If possible, I'd prefer a Python solution where coding is involved, but I'll work with whatever I can get. Simply getting the data to Google Cloud Storage (e.g. one JSON document for each call) is also acceptable; I can write a process (Dataflow or something) to handle duplicates and ingest those into BigQuery.

I feel like this question must have been asked and answered in the past, but I haven't found anything after a couple days of searching, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your suggestion of using Python to poll the API and using (for example) the Cloud Storage client libraries to get the JSON to a bucket seems reasonable. From there you could use either a pubsub notification and a cloud function or, as you've said, Dataflow (Apache Beam) to process the data. Do you have any specific doubts about doing it in one of those ways?

Comment: @Christopher What I was concerned about was how to do it reliably, but I think I've come up with a reasonable approach (in my head) since then: use App Engine Cron (scheduled minutely) to call a process that uses URL Fetch in a loop however many times per minute. Probably don't need to write to Cloud Storage; just persist directly in BigQuery. I'm hoping to try it out in the next few days and update, but any feedback over whether that seems reasonable is always welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [streaming inserts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) to do this. After polling the API with Python, you can use the BigQuery client library to stream that data directly to Bigquery [(here's an example)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery-stream-data-python).